# Django Form is not visible in Inherited template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using template inheritance in my django project. I used form in my base html page and submit button, When i inherit base template to another template form get disappeared but submit button is still there. I have below templates.

base.html

```
<head>
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bootstrap.css" %}">
</script>
</head>
<body>
     {% block option %}
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <form method = "post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
    <div class="row">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div> 
</body>
```

chart.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<head>
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bootstrap.css" %}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
</script>
</head>
    <div id="container" align="center">
        {{ column_chart.as_html }} 
{% endblock %}
```

How can i make form visible there in chart html??

EDIT: Added Views

views.py

```
def select_chart_form(request):
    form = SelectChart(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        if (str(form.cleaned_data['status']) == '1'):
            #print "Hello Naresh reverse('chart1')"
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/chart1/')
        if (str(form.cleaned_data['status']) == '2'):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/chart2/')
    context = {
               'form' : form
               }
    return render(request, 'base.html', context)

def video_by_user(request):
    analysis = VideoData.objects.annotate(watches_count = Count('user')).order_by('-watches_count')[:10]
    data_source = ModelDataSource(analysis,fields=['video_name', 'watches_count'])
    column_chart = gchart.ColumnChart(data_source,options={'title': "Top 10 Videos watched by No. Of Users"})
    context = {
                "data_source": data_source,
                "column_chart": column_chart,
               }
    return render_to_response('chart.html', context)
```

I am calling video_by_user method..after click on submit button.

Comment: you have to pass form from view to the template   ex: context_instance = RequestContext(request)
return render_to_response(template_name, {'form':form}t, context_instance)

Comment: What is the view that renders chart.html? Are you passing the form in the template context in that view?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  i edited post with Views...where i am doing wrong??

Comment: What is chart2.html in video_by_user?

Comment: @DanielRoseman its chart.html ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select_chart_form` and `video_by_user` views are completely separate. The first one renders just base.html, and supplies the `form` variable when it does so. The second one renders chart.html, which inherits from base.html, but it only supplies the variables needed for chart.html itself: it doesn't provide the form needed for base.html. You will need to supply that in `video_by_user`.

Comment: Should i use class based view for that purpose or there is some other way??

Comment: There are plenty of other ways: context processors and custom template tags, for example.